# PHP Select Option Value is wrong

Tags: php, database, select, crud

im making a select option, the value is from the database, the `CRUD` is working perfectly, but the value that i input from the select option is wrong, instead of the value the data that being inputted is the id of the data, this is my select option code

```
<select name="provinsi_dom" id="provinsi_dom">
    <?php
        //mengambil nama-nama provinsi yang ada di database
        $sqlProvinsi_dom = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM provinsi ORDER BY nama_provinsi ASC");
        echo "<option value=''>--Pilih Provinsi--</option>";
        while($p=mysqli_fetch_array($sqlProvinsi_dom)){
            if ($p['id_provinsi']==$provinsi_dom) {
                $cek="selected";
            }else {
                $cek="";
            }
            echo "<option value='$p[id_provinsi]' $cek>$p[nama_provinsi]</option>" ;    
        }
    ?>
    </select>
```

so instead of the data what being inputted is this

[image]

this is the select option value

[image]

Comment: curent of $provinsi_dom value?

Comment: Change `id_provinsi` to `nama_provinsi` in your option value.

Comment: if i do that, the value on the next select option wont show

Comment: are you trying get from post? should be: if ($p['id_provinsi']==(int)$_POST['provinsi_dom']) {

Comment: If the name of the _next_ one does not show, that suggests the name value contains a `'` or `"` character and breaks the HTML . Use htmlspecialchars `echo "<option value='" . htmlspecialchars($p['nama_provinsi'], ENT_QUOTES) . "' $cek>" . htmlspecialchars($p['nama_provinsi'], ENT_QUOTES) . "</option>" ;` http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php

Comment: it still wont show even if i use your method

Comment: Are you try get nama_provinsi or id_pronvisi?

Comment: nama_provinsi to be inserted into the database

Comment: Then, try Replace $p[id_provinsi] to $p[nama_provinsi] on line 7 and 12

Comment: already tried that, the data on the select option will show the id instead of the data, and the next select option value wont show

Comment: next select option value? Is Kota/Kab?

Comment: yes and then it goes on to kec and to kel

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181584/discussion-between-sukalogika-and-luthfi-musafa).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After discusion in chat:

User want to save "nama_provinsi" in database. 
But for some reason, id_provinsi should not be changed in view/interface.

So, the edit should be in insert query. To get nama_provinsi by id_provinsi

```
...
( SELECT nama_provinsi FROM provinsi WHERE id_provinsi = $prov), 
...
```